# Http status for error response because of business exception. Syntax is correct and request makes sense

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

There are many questions about proper response status, but I couldn't understand which status should I use for normal business exception. I've read definition of 400 and it seems to me like it for errors in communication.

> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something
>   that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request
>   syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request
>   routing).

Lets say client wants to confirm some operation. He sends me absolutely correct, valid request which I understand and process. But confirmation code is not correct. So it's an error, but this error is normal and expected, our communication is correct. Or another example: client wants to withdraw some money from account. Again, request is correct and valid, but account doesn't have enough money. I'm going to use **400** now, but **400** seems to me for errors in communication between client and server, not in application logic. Maybe there is a more appropriate status for such errors? What do you use?

Comment: refer: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html This link has explained httpd status codes

Comment: Thanks, but I know this document and I don't find any appropriate status there.

Comment: Don't think there will be an HTTP status code for all cases.  I would recommend that you return 400 with the domain specific error code in the body.

Comment: "Again, request is correct and valid, but account doesn't have enough money." This sounds like a 409 Conflict to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use HTTP 422 (Unprocessable Entity) for these cases. I prefer this rule to pick the http status codes:

- HTTP 200, 201, 204 when request processed successfully
- HTTP 422 when request violates some business rules
- HTTP 500 when unexpected exceptions are occured while processing request

Resource: [A nice blog](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/)

Comment: That blog is nice but has a few errors. It links to the [RFC7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231) standard but if you look at it, 422 is no longer part of it. So the flowcharts on that blog are outdated.

Comment: `422` is in WebDAV RFC. It is a common code used for indication of business logic errors. rfc7231 says: *HTTP status codes are **extensible**.  HTTP clients are not required to
   understand the meaning of all registered status codes, though such
   understanding is obviously desirable.  However, a client MUST
   understand the class of any status code, as indicated by the first
   digit*